# How to subtract date and time out of date time object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Here is what I am trying to achieve - I have set up a scheduler to execute midnight of every friday, which collects the data from a service for the start date of last friday at 00:00:00 hrs and end time of last thursday at 23:59:59 hrs. Since it has to work every friday, I cannot hard code the dates so I thought of trying out DateTime.

So as per my requirement, if I am running the job on this Friday midnight i.e at "2014-12-12T03:00:00Z", then my start date should be "2014-12-05T00:00:00Z" and my end date should be "2014-12-11T23:59:59Z".

So to get start and end dates, I am trying to subtract days out of my now object. This is what I tried:

```
    now = DateTime.now
    p now.new_offset(0).to_s

    startDate = now - 7
    p startDate.new_offset(0).to_s

    endDate = now - 1
    p endDate.new_offset(0).to_s
```

This gives me the right date, but the time is wrong i.e. instead of start date with 00:00:00 and end date with 23:59:59 this would be start date with 03:00:00 and end date with 03:00:00.

How do I modify the DateTime object to get the start date with time at beginning of the day and end date with time at end of the day?

Sorry I am very bad in dealing with dates. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can use: `start_date = (Date.current - 7.days).beginning_of_day` ; `end_date = (Date.current + 7.days).end_of_day`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use he [beginning_of_day](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-beginning_of_day) and [end_of_day](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-end_of_day) methods

```
1.9.3-p448 :001 > DateTime.now.beginning_of_day
 => Tue, 09 Dec 2014 00:00:00 +0300
1.9.3-p448 :002 > DateTime.now.end_of_day
 => Tue, 09 Dec 2014 23:59:59 +0300
```

Comment: I had given this a try before posting here, but not sure why it's not finding this method. I get "undefined method `beginning_of_day' for #<DateTime:0x000001017ca6d0>" error.

Comment: Here is what I used p "DateTime.now.beginning_of_day"

Comment: Rails 3.2.17 and ruby-1.9.3-p545

Comment: @tech_human [It presents for your version](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/DateTime/beginning_of_day). Are you sure it is a part of your Rails application and not just standalone Ruby script? How do you start it?

Comment: Am adding all these on the top of my class - require 'date'
require 'time'
require 'chronic'
require 'active_support'

Comment: I tried on irb too and am getting "uninitialized constant DateTime" error

Comment: Ohhh I found it. Using "require 'active_support/all'" helps.

Comment: @tech_human Yes, in irb and your script you are using default Ruby `DateTime` implementation. Rails' `active_support` provides additional functionality. In `rails console` and Rails application you don't need this `require` line.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is easier done with the Date class :

```
require 'date'
start_date = (Date.today - 7).to_time
end_date = Date.today.to_time - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this manually, I will suggest a gem called Whenever: https://github.com/javan/whenever

It's a simple DSL for Ruby cron jobs.

Also remember that DateTime has `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day` methods.